# Chrome 67 not applying monitor colour profile in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, budgie

I have enabled a monitor profile for my screen in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 via the settings (I believe this is the standard Gnome Settings).

The colour profile has both VCGT video card lookup table curves, and TRC curves that a given app (eg Chrome, Gimp, Inkscape) would use to render a given sRGB value (or a value in any colourspace) correctly within the app.

The VCGT aspect of the colour profile is loaded correctly, and my entire screen adjusts accordingly.

However, Chrome is not seeing the system monitor profile setting for some reason, and it is not doing its part when rendering colours or images.

The Gimp (2.10) picks up the colour profile correctly, and renders images as intended.

Inkscape does not automatically pick up the colour profile, even if I select "Retrieve profile from display", although it did on my previous older Ubuntu system. So perhaps this is related to the issue. However, when I explicitly load the given profile into Inkscape, it works correctly.

So there is nothing wrong with the color profile itself.

All this worked fine on a previous, older Ubuntu system, in Chrome, Gimp, and Inkscape.

Given that Chrome provides no way to select a specific colour profile, the only way I can select it is via the system monitor profile setting. As above, it's not picking this up.

What can I do? How/where does Chrome search for the system monitor profile, and is it fixable? Or is there a way to load a color profile into Chrome?